# nextjs middleware does not save cookies with response

Tags: next.js, cookies, nestjs, next.js13, next.js14

There is code for checking the user's role in the nextjs middleware, and the refreshToken is also updated from this check to nestjs

```
// middleware nextjs

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
    const response = NextResponse.next()

    const data = await authService.getSession()

    ... // check role and redirect user
}
```

```
@Get('session')
    async getSession(
        @Req() request: Request,
        @Res({ passthrough: true }) response: Response
    ) {
        const result = await this.authService.getSession(
            request.signedCookies[AuthConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN]
        )

        saveRefreshToken(response, result.tokens.refreshToken)

        return result
    }
```

```
export const saveRefreshToken = (response: Response, refreshToken: string) => {
    response.cookie(AuthConstants.REFRESH_TOKEN, refreshToken, {
        httpOnly: true,
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 15,
        sameSite: 'strict',
        signed: true,
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    })
}
```

but this refreshToken is not saved on the client; in order for it to be saved, you need to take it from the headers Set-Cookie and pass it to the response middleware yourself. Is it possible to somehow make it save the token itself and send it to the server, so that this endpoint accepts refreshToken I have to add fetch Cookie to headers